# undefined method `action' for ArticlesController(Table doesn't exist):Class - Ruby on Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got an error notification but I dont know where to search.
See attachement.

Where's the file with the included error?
I did the following instruction:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Here's my code:

```
class ArticlesController < ActiveRecord::Base
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private #description
    def article_params #description
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end #here's the end
end
```

[image]

Comment: add your `articles_controller.rb`

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Its above

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
class ArticlesController < ActiveRecord::Base
// ...
end
```

to

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
// ...
end
```

`ActiveRecord::Base` is for models.

Answer (score 2):

why the controller inherits `ActiveRecord`?

try changing `ArticlesController < ActiveRecord::Base` to `ArticlesController < ApplicationController`

Comment: Because then I get "uninitialized constant ApplicationRecord"

Comment: please look properly, `ApplicationController` not `Record`

Comment: ...And `ApplicationController` should already be defined in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`. This is a standard rails convention; the file would have been created when you ran `rails new my_project_name`.

Answer (score 0):

If application_controller.rb is not present in your project, then create one with the following code.

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

end